# Jquery Прервать продолжение for внутри each только для данного цикла

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мне нужно, чтобы цикл for перестал работать, если if условие дало false. При этом each цикл работал дальше для элементов

```
$('.item').each(function () {

    var nextItems = $(this).parent().nextAll() //берём все элементы, которые после родителя
    $(this).parent().after('<div class="ingredient-item-wrap">') // создаём див и вставляем после родителя
    var newWrap = $(this).parent().next().first(); //выбираем созданный выше див

    for (var i = 0; i < nextItems.length; i++) { //цикл по всем элементам, которые есть после родителя

        if($(nextItems[i]).find('.item').length == 0) {//если у элемента нет внутри дива с классом, тогда выполняем скрипт ниже
            if($(nextItems[i]).hasClass('wc-pao-addon-container') ) { // если у следующего элемента есть класс, тогда выполняем скрипт ниже
                newWrap.append($(nextItems[i])); // вставляем в обёртку данный блок
            }
        } else { // если у элемента внутри есть класс wc-pao-addon-heading, тогда идём ниже
            return false // прекращает оба цикла, должен прекратить данный for
        }
    } 


})
```

Скрипт работает правильно, только для первого `.item` , дальше обрывается.
Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($(nextItems[i]).find('.item').length == 0) {
  ...
} else { 
  break;
}
```

Comment: Блин, настолько просто, что не интересно даже) час потратил даром. Спасибо! Работает. Забыл про break...

Comment: @РомаХр Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: Знаю, надо было подождать 10 минут)

Comment: @РомаХр О, я и не знал. Оказывается, `.each()` прерывается, если попался `return false;` ) Т.е. если написать просто `return;` - тоже будет работаеть.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME попробую просто return, спасибо)